# Keycloak verify email using execute-actions-email endpoint

Tags: jboss, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

**My current user account setup flow**

After user creation, he receives an email that is sent using `execute-actions-email` endpoint to his email to continue his account setup by adding `UPDATE_PROFILE, UPDATE_PASSWORD, VERIFY_EMAIL` actions to the endpoint's body.

In this flow the user receives two emails one to setup his password, profile and another to verify the email.

**The required user account setup flow**

Send an email to the user to setup this password, profile and also to use the same email link to verify the user's email without receiving an another email.

**PS:**

I've removed the email field from `UPDATE_PROFILE` template. Also if `VERIFY_EMAIL` action is removed from the first flow the user's `emailVerified` attribute remains false.